# How to control prefixes of namespaces in XML document generated by XmlWriter - generated XAML with x:Type markup extension

Tags: .net, xml, xaml, xmlwriter, xamlreader

I am trying to generate XAML from XElements.

```
<Style xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Style.BasedOn>
    <StaticResource> 
      <StaticResource.ResourceKey>
        <Type xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
          <Type.TypeName>p:Window</Type.TypeName> 
        </Type>
      </StaticResource.ResourceKey>
    </StaticResource>
  </Style.BasedOn>
  ...
</Style>
```

However, I have problem with `x:Type` markup extension. It is unable to resolve the prefix `p:`, because I do not know how to force output XAML to map prefix `p` to namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation`.

Is there a way to control how prefixes of XML namespaces will be generated? Or is it possible to force `x:Type` markup extension to take XML namespace name instead of prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that:

```
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "p", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
```

Comment: Where do you put that attribute?